# How to use Bootstrap 5 with 16 or 24 columns without Sass

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need some help setting Bootstrap 5 to be 16 or 24 column instead of the default 12 columns.

I tried this [Bootstrap Customize](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) but it's an old version I want to be able to change the grid from 12 to 16 or more depend on the psd design

I want to do that from the Bootstrap itself from the files of Bootstrap. I don't use Sass/less

Can anyone guide me to change the grid from 12 to 16?

Comment: use sass https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#variables

Comment: `$grid-columns: 12 !default;` is in the Bootstrap Sass. I think it could work best to overide that in your own Sass?

Comment: @CuteCodeRob i don't use Sass can i do that without using Sass?

Comment: The only way is using SASS. If you're not comfortable with SASS use a tool like [themestr.app](https://themestr.app/customize) that will build the custom CSS for you

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it comes down to just a division of 100% by the number of cols you need.

What you can do is adding your own custom classes for 13+
For example your col-13 class will be:

```
.col-13 {
 width:calc(100% / 13);
}
```

Please keep in mind you don't support responsive behavior yet, you can add a media query where your (example) set the width on 100% when width < 768;

If you are using SASS and want to do above a little easier you can go for a setup like this:

```
$cols: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16;

@each $col in $cols {
  .col-#{$col} {
    width:calc(100% / 16 * $col);
  }
}
```

Above are all custom solutions, as mentioned above in the comments the best answer for this question should be:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#variables

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? Take a look.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <h3>24 columns</h3>
    <div class="row text-xs-center">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
                <div class="col">x</div>
              <div class="col">x</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to have 16 columns and i can use it like bootstrap for example col-lg-16 i want instead of 12 to be 16

Comment: Its a 'No'. Bootstrap using flexbox from bootstrap 4, so we can now add n number of columns by this way. But we can't directly add it like ```.col-md-16``` or ```.col-md-24```